# Nickel.rs: Receiving JSON data using HTTP POST request - rust keyword clash + fail on JSON null values

Tags: json, post, rust

I'm trying to print out the JSON data from POST requests sent by GitLab's web hooks: http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/web_hooks/web_hooks.html

I am using http://nickel.rs and am facing two obstacles at the moment:

1. To parse a JSON POST request in Nickel.rs you must define a struct that implements `Decodable`, the struct's field names must also match the JSON field names. However, GitLab's "Push events" request body contains a field named `ref`, this clashes with a Rust keyword and raises the compile time error: `` error: expected identifier, found keyword `ref` ``

Here is a short code example:

```
extern crate serialize;
extern crate nickel;

use std::io::net::ip::Ipv4Addr;
use nickel::{ Nickel, Request, Response, JsonBody, HttpRouter };

#[deriving(Decodable, Show)]
pub struct Example {
    ref: String,
}

fn main() {
    let mut server = Nickel::new();
    server.utilize(Nickel::json_body_parser());

    fn post_handler(request: &Request, response: &mut Response) {
        let example = request.json_as::<Example>().unwrap();
        println!("Example: {}", example);
    }

    server.post("/example", post_handler);
    server.listen(Ipv4Addr(127, 0, 0, 1), 6767);
}
```

Is there a way to parse the JSON data without defining a struct that has the same named fields?
Attempting to rename `ref` to `_ref` or anything else results in a task failure:

```
task '<unnamed>' failed at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', /home/rustbuild/src/rust-buildbot/slave/nightly-linux/build/src/libcore/option.rs:347
```

2. When receiving JSON data that contains null values, the program fails on unwrap.

Code example:

```
extern crate serialize;
extern crate nickel;

use std::io::net::ip::Ipv4Addr;
use nickel::{ Nickel, Request, Response, JsonBody, HttpRouter };

#[deriving(Decodable, Show)]
pub struct Example {
    foo: String,
}

fn main() {
    let mut server = Nickel::new();
    server.utilize(Nickel::json_body_parser());

    fn post_handler(request: &Request, response: &mut Response) {
        let example = request.json_as::<Example>().unwrap();
        println!("Example: {}", example);
    }

    server.post("/example", post_handler);
    server.listen(Ipv4Addr(127, 0, 0, 1), 6767);
}
```

then execute:
`curl 'http://localhost:6767/example' -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8'  --data-binary $'{ "foo": null }'`

Some of the POST requests from GitLab may contain null values (such as in their "Issue events" and "Merge request events" examples), how can I print out JSON data from these POST requests to console?

Comment: I believe that `null` values are modeled with `Option` fields, so in your case you want `Option<String>`, not `String`. As for keywords, I think there is no way to parse such values automatically - you will have to implemented `Decodable` for such structures manually.

Comment: Thank you! Manually implementing Decodable worked using Option fields worked!

Comment: Okay, if you don't mind, I'll put it as an answer so it can be found more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `null` values are modeled with `Option` fields, so in your case you want `Option<String>`, not just `String`.

As for keywords, I think there is no way to parse such values automatically - you will have to implemented `Decodable` for such structures manually. You can take as a base the code which the compiler generates for `#[deriving(Decodable)]` by running `rustc --pretty=expanded` on your crate entry file. For example, for this:

```
#[deriving(Decodable)]
struct Test {
    _ref: String
}
```

`rustc --pretty=expanded` outputs this (after manual re-indenting):

```
#![feature(phase)]
#![no_std]
#![feature(globs)]
#[phase(plugin, link)]
extern crate "std" as std;
extern crate "native" as rt;
#[prelude_import]
use std::prelude::*;
struct Test {
    _ref: String,
}
#[automatically_derived]
impl <__D: ::serialize::Decoder<__E>, __E> ::serialize::Decodable<__D, __E> for Test {
    fn decode(__arg_0: &mut __D) -> ::std::result::Result<Test, __E> {
        __arg_0.read_struct("Test", 1u, |_d|
            ::std::result::Ok(Test {
                _ref: match _d.read_struct_field("_ref", 0u, |_d| ::serialize::Decodable::decode(_d)) {
                    Ok(__try_var) => __try_var,
                    Err(__try_var) => return Err(__try_var),
                },
            })
        )
    }
}
```